# Bash get last line (combined) from stdout

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script that performs many different operations and displays the status of their completion in a clear way for the user. I need a function so that some strings can be retrieved as variables for further processing.
This is a highly simplified example:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Test script."
echo -n "1) cat file "
cat ./testfile.f &> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "$(tput hpa $(tput cols))$(tput cub 8)[OK]"
else
    echo "$(tput hpa $(tput cols))$(tput cub 8)[FAIL]"
fi
echo -n "2) make subfolder "
mkdir ./testdir &> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "$(tput hpa $(tput cols))$(tput cub 8)[OK]"
else
    echo "$(tput hpa $(tput cols))$(tput cub 8)[FAIL]"
fi
```

It take some as:

```
$./test.sh
Test script.
1) cat file                               [FAIL]
2) make subfolder                         [OK]
```

How can I get the last line (ideally, any string) during script execution? Ideally it would be using a function (so I could work with the resulting string) This string will be processed in the same script.
So far, I see only one solution: redirect the output of each echo command using tee.

**Is there any way to read the already outputted data!?**

Comment: Get the last line of what? The output of test.sh?

Comment: @mk12 >Get the last line of what? The output of test.sh?<br/>  No, it's just solved by tail. This string will be processed in the same script.

Comment: Why do you want to process the output in the _same_ script? What is wrong with using `tee`? Is a hypothetical wrapper function that uses `tee` to capture output a kind of solution you are looking for?

Comment: @Vladislav Ivanishin At the moment, the script works in this way. I'm looking for a more elegant solution, as the current script is very voluminous and you have to edit the output in places standing at a great distance from each other.

Comment: I read your question twice and still can't understand the problem. What do you mean by "last line"? Did you mean the last executed command?

Comment: @Irbis can't you just set the variable you want at the place you are outputting the lines?  That way you wouldn't need to then parse any captured output.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you have strings {1..5} that you need to process:

```
process() {
   while read -r input; do
      sleep 2
      echo "Processed ${input}."
   done
}

printf "line %s\n" {1..5} | process
```

In this situation you might want to see the numbers before they are being processed.
You can do this by duplicating stdout to `fd 3` and use a function.

```
display() {
   while read -r input; do
      echo "=== ${input} ===" >&3
      echo "${input}"
   done
}

process() {
   while read -r input; do
      sleep 2
      echo "Processed ${input}."
   done
}

exec 3>&1
printf "line %s\n" {1..5} | display | process
```